# Automatic Spool Sending

Tags: spool, sap-basis

in FMS system I need to automatically send the spool of a given background job let say job 'B'.
Job B is generated by a different background job, let say job 'A'. SM36 has the possibility to send only A job spool. Any suggestions?

Already tried SM36 tcode